# In a list, how to print which line has a certain element

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find out on what line in the list the popular name shows up so I can get the ranking of that name, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.

I'm thinking doing something like this, but I don't know how to stop the loop when the popular name is reached

```
x=0
for number in myfile:
x+=1
```

My current code is

```
print("Enter a name to see if it is a popular girls or boys name.")
name=[]
boyfile=open('BoyNames.txt','r')
boynames=boyfile.read().splitlines()
girlfile=open('GirlNames.txt','r')
girlnames=girlfile.read().splitlines()
while name!='stop':
    popularname=input("Enter a name, or enter stop to stop: ")
    popularname=popularname.rstrip('\n')
    if popularname=='stop':
        break
    if popularname in  boynames:
            print("{} is a popular boys name".format(popularname))
    else:
        print("{} is not a popular boys name".format(popularname))
    if popularname in girlnames:
        print("{} is a popular girls name".format(popularname))
    else:
        print("{} is not a popular girls name".format(popularname))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to search for an element in a list? Python's sequence types have method `index` for this:

```py
print(['Beavis', 'Butt-head', 'Daria'].index('Beavis'))
```